# How to simulate a bold font if I only have a Regular Height TTF file?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

How can I simulate a bold font if I only have a Regular Height TTF file?

I'm trying to use **Ibarra Real** font, but I have only Italic and Regular font files.

Using xelatex and a preamble like:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Extension=.ttf,BoldFont=IBregular,ItalicFont=IBitalic,Numbers=OldStyle]{IBregular}
```

I can see it, but `\textbf` is the same as normal text.

Is it possible to modify font weight in latex?

Comment: In the name of all that is holy, please do not do this.  Just [download the bold version of the typeface](http://www.unostiposduros.com/unostiposduros-distribuye-la-tipografia-ibarra-real/)!  Faked bolds should be eliminated.

Comment: I used the download zip at ibarrareal.es , Better with you link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have that font, so I used (actually abused) EB Garamond, but it should work the same with your font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  BoldFont=EBGaramond12-Regular,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
  ItalicFont=EBGaramond12-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=EBGaramond12-Italic,
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]{EBGaramond12-Regular}

\begin{document}
Abc \textbf{Abc} \textit{Abc} \textbf{\textit{Abc}}
\end{document}
```

Adjust the emboldening factor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Yori linked a version with bolds, but your response is the think I was looking for.

Comment: @Zhen Considering what the Ibarra Real font is, I would advise you ***not*** to use boldface with it. As I use to say, it's like Ben Hur wearing a wristwatch.